# Python: TypeError: descriptor 'strip' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'

Tags: python, package

I am learning how to use a package to process MRS data: http://suspect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/tut01_intro.html

When I run these first few lines of the tutorial:

```
import suspect
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = suspect.io.load_rda("Phantom1_svs_30.rda")
print(data)
```

I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'strip' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'
```

Here's the Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-35cc3220407a> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 data = suspect.io.load_rda("Phantom1_svs_30.rda")
      3 print(data)

C:\Users\VK\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\suspect\io\rda.pyc in load_rda(filename)
     41         header_line = fin.readline().strip().decode('windows-1252')
     42         while header_line != ">>> End of header <<<":
---> 43             key, value = map(str.strip, header_line.split(":", 1))
     44             if key in rda_types["strings"]:
     45                 header_dict[key] = value

TypeError: descriptor 'strip' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'
```

Is the error in a package file?

Comment: full traceback (in the question) please

Comment: I suspect (no pun intended) it is in the library and you're probably looking for a `str.split` in there..

Comment: Are you using Python2? `str.strip(u'a')` will raise such an error in Python2, not in Python3. This library is intended for use with Python3 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suspect/0.2.0.

Comment: @dzejdzej Thanks. I will try it with Python 3.

Comment: @dzejdzej Now that I am using Python3, I am getting another error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydicom'. Suspect uses a package (pydicom), which requires Python2. What to do?

Comment: @Beginner did you install pydicom from Github? It looks like you have PyPi version installed. Suspect specifies how to do it https://github.com/openmrslab/suspect/blob/master/README.rst. It looks like they transitioned from name "dicom" to "pydicom".

Comment: @dzejdzej Yes I have. It works now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Beginner: If you have a new question, ask a new question instead of completely changing your existing question.